# How to create joi schema to validate object of objects

Tags: validation, object, schema, joi

I tried to make schema to validate json such this:

```
 {
  "integration": { "module": [ "m" ] },
  "tile": {
    "title": "TTT",
    "text": "ttt",
    "icon": "./resources/main-icon.png",
    "tags": [ "bbb", "vvvv"],
    "orderNumber": 20
  },
  "steps": {
    "order": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
    ],
    "data": {
      "1": {
        "title": "tt1",
        "description": "",
        "screens": { "default": "true" }
      },
      "2": {
        "title": "tt2",
        "description": "",
        "screens": { "default": "true" }
      },
      "3": {
        "title": "tt3",
        "description": "",
        "screens": { "default": "true" }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Schema:

```
Joi.object({
  integration: Joi.object({
    module: Joi.array().items(Joi.string().valid('m').required())
    }).required(),
  tile: Joi.object({
    title: Joi.string().required(),
    text: Joi.string().required(),
    icon: Joi.string().required(),
    tags: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).required(),
    orderNumber: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(255).required()
  }).required(),
  steps: Joi.object({
    order: Joi.array().items(Joi.string()).required(),
    data: Joi.object().keys({
      title: Joi.string().required(),
      description: Joi.string().required(),
      screens: Joi.object({
        default: Joi.string().valid('true', 'false').required()
      }).required()
    }).unknown(),
  }).required()
});
```

But it generate error:

Validation Error: "steps.data.title" is required. "steps.data.description" is required. "steps.data.screens" is required

Please help. How can I make this schema?

Answer (score 0):

Your data key is an object with keys 1, 2, and 3, each one is also an object with keys title, description, and screens.

But in your validation, your data key is an object with keys title, description, and screens, which is not correct.

You should change your steps.data validation to this:

```
data: Joi.object().pattern(
    Joi.string().valid("1", "2", "3"),
    Joi.object().keys({
        title: Joi.string().required(),
        description: Joi.string().required().allow(''),
        screens: Joi.object({ default: Joi.string().valid('true', 'false').required() }),
    })).unknown(),
}).required()
```

I used [Joi.object().pattern](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema-options) to avoid duplicating the code since your object value is the same for each key.

I also changed your data.description, since you were not allowing empty strings, I just added [.allow('')](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyallowvalues).